# Using Angular to declare a new service instance per module?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using angular. I already know that when an appmodule is importing modules which declares `providers`, the root injector gets them all and the service is visible to the app - globally. (*I'm not talking about lazy loaded modules*)

But is it possible that each `module` will have its own instance of the service?

I thought of maybe something like this :

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [AService]
})
class A {
    forRoot() {
        return {
            ngModule: A,
            providers: [AService]
        }
    }

    forChild() {
        return {
            ngModule: A,
            providers: [AService]
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't know if it's the right way of doing it

**Question**

How can I accomplish service per module ?

[**STACKBLITZ** : from my testing , they are using the same service instance](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7vnhio?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts)

Answer (score 1):

> When we provide a service in a feature module that is eagerly loaded
>   by our app's root module, it is available for everyone to inject. - [John Papa](https://johnpapa.net/introducing-angular-modules-feature-modules-2/)

So looks like there is no way to inject at feature-module level, as there are no module level injectors other than the one at root module.

But angular has nodes at each component level for the injector, so such a scenario will have to use coponent level-injectors I guess.

You can also have a parent component inject the service for different children sharing the same instance.

One way is to provide the services at component level. Not sure if that will work for you.

Also, check the [multiple edit scenario in the docs](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#scenario-multiple-edit-sessions)

https://angular-iayenb.stackblitz.io

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CounterService} from "../../counter.service"
@Component({
  selector: 'c2',
  templateUrl: './c2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./c2.component.css'],
  providers:[CounterService]
})
export class C2Component implements OnInit {

  constructor(private s:CounterService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

> Question
>
> How can I accomplish service per module ?

Not with the default Injector. Default Injector keeps nodes at root level and component level, not at feature-module level. You will have to have a custom Injector if there is a real scenario.

Comment: Are you looking for a service that will have instances per feature module? Or a module with exported service that you can import to different feature modules, but will have different instances of the exported service?

Comment: instance per module

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:** the previous answer from me is not completely correct. The correct way to make this work is to use lazy loaded modules, provide the services there. The given service should not be provided with a static forRoot() method somewhere because then the lazy loaded module will access the root injector.

There is no actual reference to do so because that is not how angular is designed but if you want it that way you have to the opposite of

https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#providing-a-singleton-service

and

https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#forroot

**Old not completely correct:**
You simple have to declare the service you want to be single instance for each and every module within the providers meta data of each and every module. Then Angular will not reuse any instance of the service.

Giving scenario: You have two modules, ModuleA and ModuleB, both need the service but different instance, then you will declare them in the providers section of ModuleA and ModuleB.

Reference:
https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Comment: Aren't they merged to the global injector ?

Comment: From my testing , they are the same instance : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7vnhio?file=app/app.module.ts

Comment: You are importing Module1 into Module2 then export it again from there and  import only Module2 into AppModule. Isn't that the cause?

Comment: I've noticed that , but even when i imported them seperatly , it was the same instance. - see for yourself - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7vnhio?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: That is indeed very interesting. Usually it should do that, maybe it is a bug? A service that should be a global singleton has to be declared as such (https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services) otherwise it should be an instance per module.

Comment: It's not odd , it's the normal behaviour. all injectors go to top.But that I already knew

Comment: I updated the post based on research. Lazyloaded modules is the only way to approach this currently.